# Desktop refuses to spread across dual monitors

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors

Set up dual monitors on my friends fresh install of Ubuntu 11.10
Monitor 1 = 20" is first (original screen)
Monitor 2 = 15" flat screen.
These screens work fine cloned but when I try to spread desktop across the 2 monitors the ATI utility exits without error not changing anything and the Ubuntu utility produces an out of range message saying "requested position/size for CRTC 147 is outside the allowed limit ; position (1024,0), size (1024,768) , maximum (1680,1680)"

This makes no sense at all and would make a fine Micro$loth error message indeed !

Or am I just dense ?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

The AMD (ATI) propietary drivers does not support multiple screens in Ubuntu 11.10 (Not yet) I'm waiting for a new release as well :(